# How to skip a dialogue UNITY - Need help, the code for the dialogue works but not for skipping it :'

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, dialog

Guys I made a code for a dialogue system in Unity but I'm confused on how to make it skip. It runs well, but I just need it so I can skip it if it takes too long.

```
private IEnumerator StartDialogue()
{
    if (outOfRange == false)
    {
        int dialogueLength = dialogueLines.Length;
        int currentDialogueIndex = 0;

        while (currentDialogueIndex < dialogueLength || !letterIsMultiplied)
        {
            if (!letterIsMultiplied)
            {
                letterIsMultiplied = true;
                StartCoroutine(DisplayString(dialogueLines[currentDialogueIndex++]));

                if (currentDialogueIndex >= dialogueLength)
                {
                    dialogueEnded = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Input.GetKeyDown(DialogueInput))
                    {
                        StopAllCoroutines();
                        currentDialogueIndex = dialogueLength;
                    }
                }
            }
            yield return 0;
        }

        while (true)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(DialogueInput) && dialogueEnded == false)
            {
                break;
            }
            yield return 0;
        }
        dialogueEnded = false;
        dialogueActive = false;
        DropDialogue();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have set up the code so that if the currentDialogue >= dialoguelength then the first dialogue will end,  I tried to use this code for the "else" so that it can stop the coroutine and immediately fill the box but it still not skipping

```
                else
                {
                    if (Input.GetKeyDown(DialogueInput))
                    {
                        StopAllCoroutines();
                        currentDialogueIndex = dialogueLength;
                    }
                }
```

and yes i'm still new to this so don't hate me :'

Answer (score 1):

if I understand well what you did, the problem is effectively in the else if block where you stop all your coroutines.

The thing is that `StopAllCoroutines()` effectively stops all the coroutine that are running on this very gameObject. So when you call this method, it stops the `StartDialogue` and the `DisplayString` coroutines.

What you are missing is that you set `currentDialogueIndex` well at the end of the string but you never display the text after that.

You just need to display the full text when you skip, everything is setup, now it's up to you !

Hope that helped and nobody hates you ;)

Comment: I get it for the StopAllCoroutine, but for the display part I am a bit confused. Because the display is correspondent to the length of the dialogueLines in this case dialogueLength. So should I just post the dialogueLines???

Comment: You can call the `DisplayString` with `currentDialogueIndex` or `dialogueLength`. You should have something somewhere that set all your dialgue lines into the `text` property of your `Text` component

Comment: Ah ok, let me try it. I'll get back to you when I'm done! Thank you!!!!